# Geometric interpretation of sheaf cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, sheaf-theory

Please forgive me for the informal and naïve nature of my question, as I am a beginner in algebraic geometry.

In the famous book by Hartshorne, sheaf cohomology is defined as a certain derived functor.

Is it possible to show that the sheaf cohomology of a sheaf is equal to some singular cohomology of a topological space?

For example, it is known that a sheaf on a topological space can be interpreted as an étale space, but in this case, do the sheaf cohomology and the singular cohomology of the étale  space of the sheaf coincide?

Comment: Singular cohomology is sheaf cohomology for constant sheaves (or local systems), for nice spaces.

Comment: This is not quite the answer you are looking for, but by writing an element $a$ of $\mathrm{H}^1(X,F)=\mathrm{Ext}^1(O_X,F)$, we see that there is an extension $0\to F\to E_a\to O_X\to 0$. Pulling back the section $1$ of $O_X$, we get a "torsor" $T_a$ which is the etale space of a sheaf of sets with an "$F$-action". This kind of approach only works with $\mathrm{H}^1$.

Answer (score 14):

It is impossible to interpret sheaf cohomology as singular cohomology of any space. This is because the degree 0 singular cohomology of any space is nontrivial unless the space is empty, in which case all the singular cohomology groups vanish, but it is easily possible for sheaf cohomology to vanish in degree $0$ but be nonvanishing in higher degree.

However there is a notion of singular cohomology with coefficients in a locally constant sheaf (i.e. a representation of the fundamental group, i.e. a local system) which involve cochains that instead of assigning a number to each simplex, assign a section of the local system over that simplex, and coboundary maps involve choosing unique extensions of sections. This will agree in reasonable cases with sheaf cohomology, so one can think of sheaf cohomology as a generalization of this (arguably more geometric) construction.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another observation that might convince you that sheaf cohomology is not really a topological invariant, but is rather either an algebraic or complex analytic invariant.

On $\mathbb{P}^1$, we have the two rank $2$ vector bundles $$\mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^1}$$ and
$$\mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)\oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2).$$ The first bundle has $H^0 = \mathbb{C}^2$ and $H^1 = 0$ and the second has $H^0 = \mathbb{C}^3$ and $H^1 = \mathbb{C}^1$.

However, from the smooth point of view, the total spaces of these vector bundles are actually diffeomorphic.  In fact, we can continuously vary the extension class $e\in \mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2),\mathcal O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2))$ to define a rank $2$ vector bundle $$0\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2) \to V_e \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)\to 0.$$  For a general $e\neq 0$, this bundle will be $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$, and for $e=0$ the bundle will be $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)$.  These vector bundles $V_e$ then all fit together to give a family of rank $2$ vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$, and by Ehresman's theorem they will be diffeomorphic to one another.

There can therefore be no purely topological construction which takes a sheaf and determines the sheaf cohomology.  As an ingredient in any hypothetical construction, you will have to use the complex analytic or algebraic data more explicitly.  For instance, the global section functor knows about the algebraic or holomorphic sections of the sheaf, so that the derived functor formalism is inherently using algebraic or holomorphic data about the sheaf.

Comment: Yes, although the question-asker suggested using the étale space as the underlying topological space rather than the vector bundle, and the étale space would distinguish these two sheaves (at least when combined with the map to the base space).